# bundle install failing while Installing eventmachine 1.0.3

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler

while bundle installing it failed at below step..

```
Installing dotenv 0.11.1
Installing eventmachine 1.0.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... no
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
creating Makefile
make "DESTDIR=" clean
make "DESTDIR="
generating rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def
The system cannot find the path specified.
make: *** [rubyeventmachine-x64-mingw32.def] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.1.0
/eventmachine-1.0.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot
```

continue.
    Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.

please help on how to rectify?? Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to install `libssl`. Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libssl`. MacOS: `sudo brew install openssl`.

Comment: @mudasobwa how to install in windows? and after installing do i run bundle install allover again? i am afraid it might start downloading all gems again and there might be version conflict or something like that..
can anyone please help?
Thanks a lot....

Comment: Google for “install openssl on windows.” `bundle install` after is required, but it will now download anything that is already downloaded.

Comment: @mudasobwa you mean what are already downloaded will be ignored and only new ones will be downloaded ? :-)..thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in `eventmachine 1.0.3` that prevents it from building using the `DevKit-x64` compiler.

You can either upgrade the `eventmachine` gem to a newer version or use a *32-bit* version of Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for responding . eventmachine 1.0.3 is not in gem file..its like some sort of dependency gem that's called internally . So like you said i thought of executing eventmachine 1.0.4 manually using the command
       gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.4'
but still its showing the same error...i thought the reason could be i needed mingw32 .To reinstall 32-bit ruby in 64 bit windows laptop can be a disaster any advice please. thank you

Comment: Actually no, 32-bit Ruby works fine on 64-bit Windows. In fact, the **suggested** setup is to run 32-bit Ruby. 64-bit Ruby is provided because in some instances (embedded and special virtualized servers) 32-bit redirection is unavailable or some instances where 64-bit Ruby is required for special tasks.

Comment: as you said it installed ruby 2.1.6 32-bit version and eventmachine problem has failed...but i got stuck at http_parser.rb 0.6.0...i am not sure what its problem is ..its throwing similar error...is there anyway of finding out which gem has called this they are all in one queue cant really determine..and more over under my c:/ there are two MinGW-4.8.1 and MinGW..is that a problem? thanks so much

Comment: Under your `Gemfile.lock`. You're going to have to give more information on the new errors and such. I don't have enough information to know what the problem with `http_parser.rb` is. Also there is a different DevKit for 32-bit and 64-bit Rubies. Be sure the right one is installed.

Comment: yeah just now i realized that i did not have a devkit and installed devkit for 32 bit and the above error got rectified now stuck with new one..here it is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234917/gem-kgio-2-9-2-installation-error