# Error Installing "kgio-2.9.2" Gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows

Having problems installing the kgio gem on Windows

Using Ruby 2.1.6 32-bit & DevKit installed.

```
Installing kgio 2.9.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
checking for clockid_t in time.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib

extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/kgio-2.9.2
 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/kgi
o-2.9.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing kgio (2.9.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install kgio -v '2.9.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 4):

Running Windows 7, this worked for me:

[rails unicorn install error with kgio 2.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388631/rails-unicorn-install-error-with-kgio-2-8-0)

`platforms :ruby do 
  gem 'unicorn'
end`

Answer (score 1):

The [`kgio` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/kgio/versions/2.9.3) is meant to run on Unix systems and doesn't have any support for Windows systems.

Comment: so if i comment it there might be some dependency issues...is there any alternative for it in windows? i mean a substitute?

Comment: i heard there is a gem called thin which is its substitute in windows..is it correct and moreover whats the different between gems thin and slim are they same or different?thanks for your patience

Comment: All I know is that `thin` is a web server. I don't know what your project is or how it would handle other web servers.

Comment: thanks that issue is solved but something new came up
here it is 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236420/rugged-gem-installation-issue-possibly-with-lingit2-on-windows

Comment: If your problem is solved you should accept the answer as the "accepted answer", by clicking the check mark next to the votes. =)

Comment: @Matthias I guess in the sense of a solution I didn't. In the sense that I explained that there is no solution is a correct answer.